# Convert ex.getLocalizedMessage(); in a JSON

Tags: java, json, error-handling

In handling the error from a third-party API I get this message (a String Object) from the getLocalizedMessage() method:

```
"400 Bad Request: "{"reason":"No data is available for this location","error":true}"
```

What I would like to handle is to take the reason contained in the message and use it for my error handling. I thought about using Jackson Library but I don't know if that is the best way to do this task.